Requested Query String is too long: Error with Edge using Angular 16 & 17
Appreciate if someone gave an insight into this matter. I deployed my Angular 17 files into server using the command "ng build --configuration production". When I ran the app in server using Edge,
I get the below screenshot.

I got the same in Chrome too. Till deployment, I didn't get this error in my system. After getting issue in server, it started appearing in my system too.
Tried again with Angular 16. Error disappeared in Chrome, but remains in Edge (both private & normal windows). And I'm unable to replicate this properly in my system, running in localhost.
Once login is successful, I'll be redirected to homepage. But, instead of going to homepage, the application stops in this screen. Even if I hard refresh by Emptying cache, I am not able to reach login page.[Issue]
Appreciate any form of information, whether it's related to any package/browser compatibility.
Angular 16/17.
With SSO(Azure App) using oauth2 oidc.
.NET Core 8.
Thanks in Advance.

why not use "POST" instead of "GET"?

How long is your querystring?

Issue is probably the url used for authentication with Azure Active Directory, which is limited to 2048 characters. Using a POST avoids this limitation.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Could you copy the url from current AADSTS90015: Requested query string is too long error page? And hide your sensitive information by using *, we need to double-check the details. As we know this url is generated by AAD, what we only do is just setting the redirect-url.

Hi @Bouke,
I have seen the GET replacement with POST method when I searched in a few blogs and other communities for this, previously, but couldn't get any clarification such as why/where do we need to make changes and the uses of changing it. Where can I make the changes? Is it in AAD?

Hi @Eliseo, same query to you.
